# Logging Into Site Using Javascript HTTP Request?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, httprequest, parse-cloud-code, http-request

I'm attempting to log into my nike account using http requests and parse. Here's my request:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      },
      url: 'https://www.nike.com/profile/login',
      params: {
          'Content-Locale' : 'en_US',
      },
      body: {
          'login' : <userId>,
          'rememberMe' : 'true',
          'password' : '<password>'
      }
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {

      //Log
      console.log(httpResponse.text);
    }, function(httpResponse) {

      //Log
      console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

I'm using rest to call my function, and it's working correctly. The only problem is that it keeps returning a `403` error. Is there something I'm doing wrong with my request?

Here is all the info of the actual request I found in Safari when logging in through the browser (NOTE: I'm new to http requests).

[image]

## Update:

The image above is of a valid login using the web browser.

Also, here's an image of the request and response section for more details:

[image]

Comment: Is it an image of a failed request or is that one valid?

Comment: there is an OPTION request to do before

Comment: This one is valid. A failed one returns a 401 code.

Comment: Could you post the `request & response` section? Without the sensitive information of course.

Comment: @MinusFour Sure. Just updated my answer :)

Comment: Is the `Request & Response` submenu just for show? What I'd do is grab the raw HTTP request and replicate that as best as you can. I have never used safari network inspector but it might be not showing all the headers sent.

Comment: Hmm. What do you recommend I use to get the full headers? Chrome or firefox? Sorry for asking a noob question, but how would I get the raw HTTP request?

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Can you explain a bit more? Thanks :)

Comment: @KingPolygon, first I'd start by replicating all the headers that safari show you. `Referer`, `Origin`, `User-Agent`, `Accept`, `DNT`.

Comment: @MinusFour Thanks. Tried that but nothing. Pierre mentioned that an OPTIONS request has to be done before the POST. Not sure how that should be done.

Comment: My guess is that nike.com has some hard security protection which checks not only header params but also your cookies refferer page etc  to identify that request was made from their own page then only allows you to login, totally same data should be sent from your side as i see you are missing cookies in your request try to include it also and all params which sent in your browser login request

Comment: I would put money on it being CORS, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: It would be useful to see your actual 403 error to determine whether it is a CORS response from your browser, or a real 403 response from the server.  Sometimes this is hard to tell from a browsers dev tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything wrong with your request structure, if you are consistently seeing `403 - Forbidden` response. That implies that your request is being rejected due to cross-origin restrictions, improper or unexpected request headers and/or spoofing your referrer and origin, etc.

But without knowing the details of Nike's login services, we can only speculate.

I would expect to see other HTTP responses like `400 Bad Request`, `406 Not Acceptable`, `500 Timeout`, etc if there was something fundamentally wrong with your request.

To properly answer, we'd need to know more details about the environment your requests are made from. Is this a local server? Are you a Nike developer with access to internal nike.com environments? Where is this HTTP request being initiated from?

The best I can suggest with the information provided is some tools to help troubleshoot further:

- [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/): to monitor all outgoing requests + responses
- [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/):  for convenient testing of request structures in a more pure, browser/tech agnostic way

I can't post more than 2 links yet, but search for `cross origin access` and `http status codes` for more details on general HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

As rkd sais, 403 is Forbidden. Server is rejecting yout request. I think is not a cross-origin restriction because in the second image apperars ***Access-control-allowed:true***. Check if there is a previous cookie setted. look at the first image, in headers if there is a "set-cookie" and it values. But at all, more information about headers is needed for a better response.